# Is it better to daven a"tartei desasrei" mincha/maariv with a minyan or in the correct time without a minyan?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, zemanim, maariv, mincha-afternoon-prayer

According to [Mishnah Berura 233:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.233.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), it sounds like if the only available minyan was "tartei desasrei," i.e. mincha after plag and maariv immediately after, it would still be preferable than davening alone.

However, in [Mishnah Berura 267:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.267.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and Biur Halacha "uviflag," it seems to follow that davening "tartei desasrei" is never a valid option.

Does anyone know what would be considered better?

Answer (score 4):

In 233 he is talking about those communities which always pray *mincha* and *ma’ariv* together after *plag*, because they cannot gather a *minyan* otherwise.

In 267 he’s talking about a community which normally prays *ma’ariv* late. In such a case, he says that they should do that on Friday evening as well.

Thus, there is no contradiction. In the absence of any other option, one prays with a *minyan*, even if it means praying *mincha* and *ma’ariv* together after *plag*. However, wherever possible, it is preferable that a *minyan* not do that, even on Friday evening.